# Getting Failure response after a successful post on Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
05-09 08:59:33.258 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: --> POST http://DOMAINHIDDEN.com/solicitation/create?X-Authorization=dda15b84304fe58cbcc4f6570363 http/1.1
05-09 08:59:33.258 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
05-09 08:59:33.258 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 183
05-09 08:59:33.259 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: {"description":"descript22222222ion goes here","file":"file goes here","geolat":"31","geolong":"32","location":"list","protocol":"203120312","type":"2xx","userid":"use2rid goes here"}
05-09 08:59:33.259 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: --> END POST (183-byte body)
05-09 08:59:33.267 14174-14248/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-09 08:59:33.319 14174-14248/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
05-09 08:59:33.322 14174-14248/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-09 08:59:33.416 14174-14174/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
05-09 08:59:33.646 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://DOMAINHIDDEN.com/solicitation/create?X-Authorization=dda15b84304fe58cbcc4f6570363 (386ms)
05-09 08:59:33.646 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Date: Tue, 09 May 2017 11:59:34 GMT
05-09 08:59:33.646 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
05-09 08:59:33.646 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
05-09 08:59:33.646 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
05-09 08:59:33.646 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With
05-09 08:59:33.646 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
05-09 08:59:33.646 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
05-09 08:59:33.647 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImM3XC9KSE8yMVh0ZGpZWEt0UUNFTmd3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IitQSjZhallLekdaKzNLTDFZZFQ1ZFBXOG5IbUNCM1duUFpMS3ZvV0hUdVJQeUdqTzdlQTNJakk3ODlGOVo4YzNRWXJrT2tZVEMxT3VkcnhuMHZVY013PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI3YTlhMDlmNTMwY2ZjYzk0YjFhN2UzNWE5OGVjYzEwYWQ2YjllMGQyZjUxODM0Y2VkZjU4NmI3YjUyNDM0OTEwIn0%3D; expires=Tue, 09-May-2017 13:59:34 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
05-09 08:59:33.647 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InJXM0s5c1NDbnF2M1BlZXNTa0pqalE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiV3Eyc1hST3kxRzdoTEVFajBzdSs4emZcL0ZvXC9TMVNBUUZucnB2VDNcL3ozZkc1cjBvR042RmlhZDRMSGtIcDZtWk44V1o0T3V4TE1uREFQdlVyWFJHZVE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjRiMWNhYzQ2MTg5MGViN2RiN2I3YTVlMWQxN2M5YzNjODQ0ODJmYmIwNjg5NzM3ZGUwNGM3NDhmZDEyMTk5YjQifQ%3D%3D; expires=Tue, 09-May-2017 13:59:34 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
05-09 08:59:33.647 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 0
05-09 08:59:33.647 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
05-09 08:59:33.647 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
05-09 08:59:33.647 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
05-09 08:59:33.647 14174-14247/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

As you can see above, I get `OkHttp: <-- 200 OK`.

If I'm getting a 200 OK, why the heck the callback response coming back through `onFaiure`.

## Edit Code Below

```
    Solicitation solicitation = new Solicitation("2xx", "list", "31", "32", "descript22222222ion goes here", "file goes here", "use2rid goes here", "203120312");

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<Solicitation> call = apiService.createSolicitation(API_KEY, solicitation);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Solicitation>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Solicitation> call, Response<Solicitation> response) {
            Log.d("Response::", "Success!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Solicitation> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Response::", "Fail!!");
        }
    });
```

The above code is placed onCreate method just for testing. ApiInterface has 2 methods, one to retrieve and one to create, I'm using the create method above. It works, but it still returns failure nonetheless.

The final line of the log goes like this:

```
05-09 08:59:33.663 14174-14174/com.example.ga.retrofitposttest E/Response::: Fail!!
```

Which is precisely what I coded in `onFailure`.

Comment: post your code what you have done

Comment: I just edited..

Comment: The problem might be in your backend..test it on the postman first are you getting the proper response or not..?

Comment: Yeah, pretty regular response. Edit: tested on insomnia with the same amount of data, [this is the result](https://i.snag.gy/FCvufz.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that Retrofit hit onFailure even though the call returned 200 it failed to parse the response as it's zero length and text/html - are you expecting JSON back? Inspect Throwable t to check the exception being thrown by Retrofit.

Comment: How do I inspect throwable t?

Comment: Debug the app and put a breakpoint on the line Log.e("Response::", "Fail!!"); then check the value in Android Studio in the Debug tab

Comment: [This is what I got](https://i.snag.gy/Oy8RKZ.jpg) - No idea what to do with it.. **edit**, I'm not expecting anything back, [this is the response when I do it with the same data on insomnia](https://i.snag.gy/FCvufz.jpg).

Comment: Fixed it by returning json on the api code, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No probs, glad you got it fixed